# I can't connect to ms sql instance - internal

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, redhat, sql-server-2017

The Platform and Software versions I am using are as follows :

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU3-GDR) (KB4052987) - 14.0.3015.40 (X64) 
Dec 22 2017 16:13:22 
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) on
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600:) (Hypervisor)
I have searched a lot for answers on Google but haven't found any solution yet. I can't connect to RDS instance having MS SQL instance via Linux.
```

It shows following errors If I try to :

```
[ec2-user@ip-~]$ sqlcmd -H mssqldb.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com -P 1433
                        -U userXXXXX -P aXXXXXX
                        -Q 'SELECT TOP 1 [n] FROM [dbbase2].[dbo].[table_people]'

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server :
               Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server :
               TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server :
               A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
               establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server is not found
               or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL
               Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more
               information see SQL Server Books Online.

[ec2-user@ip- ~]$  Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
                   configured to allow remote connections.
```

Could anyone please tell the issue and resolution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, starting with the clues in the error message, did you verify if it was a named instance, and did you verify that remote connections are allowed? Next, are you sure you are able to telnet to that server on port 1433, and have you verified with AWS support that your instance is actually running on port 1433?

Comment: I checked in Linux. I run: 
sqlcmd -S EC2XXXX-SERVERNAME\INSTANCE,1433
 [ec2-user@ip-1 ~]$ sqlcmd -S EC2XXXX-SERVERNAME\INSTANCE,1433
In Windows, this works and port is open every time: telnet instance.XX..rds.amazonaws.com 1433
When I am checking telnet in Linux I see after a few seconds:Trying 1XX.XX.XXX.XXX...Connected to INSTANCE.X.rds.amazonaws.com.Escape character is '^]'.Connection closed by foreign host.